# rep points not working?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

My rep on [superuser](https://superuser.com/users/2345/cdenker) shows 101, yet I have 11 upvotes, should it not be 110? Is there a delay before it shows up? I have not noticed the same on SO or SF.

Answer (score 4):

The question you answered is community wiki, you don't get reputation points for those.

Read the [FAQ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow) on community wiki for more.